# load level dynamically using andengine in android

Tags: android, andengine

I am developing a game using andEngine in android, I've developed animated sprites background, platforms and scores. for loading level, I've made a

> .lvl 
>   extension file in which I've defined platforms, player and obstacles at fixed positions. I want to know is there anything provided by andEngine so that I can dynamically load obstacles, platforms, coins and other objects rather than loading any file, my aim is to keep my game-world going as long as my player is alive.
>   I think I am clear.
>   Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point you to investigate "TimerHandler" as your dynamic time handler (Defining how often to attach another object/entity.
With a time handler in place, you can assign nearly any int/double/float value of an object/entity with MathUtils.random(min, max).

Example:

```
TimerHandler objectTimerHandler = new TimerHandler(1f, true, new ITimerCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {

        int timerSeconds = 0;
        timerSeconds++;

        final Sprite object1 = new Sprite(0, 0, resourcesManager.object1_region, vbom);

        if (timerSeconds == MathUtils.random(1, 4))
        {
            attachChild(object1);
            object1.setX(MathUtils.random(0, 480));
        }
});
registerUpdateHandler(objectTimerHandler);
```

So, the TimeHandler "objectHandler" is called every 1 seconds defined by the 1f variable.
An integer counter "timerSeconds" is setup as a base.
The Sprite object/entity is initialized.

Now the "magic": the if boolean is in place to set a sense of true randomness. So here's the math... Every second passed, add a "timerSecond". Then, IF "timerSecond" is EQUAL to a random number between 1-4, then attach the sprite "object1" and set it's X position, also on a random range 0-480.

In reality, this means for every 1 second passed, there is a 1/4 chance that this sprite will be created/attached. (this can be altered to any desired chance range by changing that random range max value. EG: MathUtils.random(1, 100) <-- this would state a 1 in 100 chance to spawn the sprite each second.)

The 2nd to last line closes the Timehandler code, and the last line registers the Timehandler to the class/scene/entity/engine (ect..).